# How to prevent a Javascript disabled button from re-enabling after postback?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

The following code sample demomstrates the problem. 
When Button1 is clicked, Button3 is disabled through JavaScript. Clicking Button2 causes a server event that intitiates the postback. After the postback Button3 is no longer disabled.

**ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestDisableButton.aspx.cs" Inherits="StudentForms_CaseManagement_TestDisableButton" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function Button1_onclick() {
            document.getElementById("<%= Button3.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Disable Button 3" onclick="return Button1_onclick()" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Perform Post Back" onclick="Button2_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button3" />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CodeBehind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class StudentForms_CaseManagement_TestDisableButton : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Button 2 clicked";
    }
}
```

Comment: How about a hidden field that gets populated by your click event with the enabled state of your button? Your code-behind could read that and disable the button as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On postback disable your Button3

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button3.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The button is recreated on the server side, based on it's latest state (stored in `ViewState`, which goes from server to browser and back to server), and the posted value.

The problem is that the disabled state is in the `ViewState` and you cannot modify it on the client side. The only posted value is the value of the control itself (for example the text in a text box).

So, as you cannot modify the `ViewState`, the only alternative is to have an extra control in your form tha allows to post the disabled state back to the sever. So you need to add a `HiddenField`, set its state on the client side (in the same script that enables/disables the button), and then, on the server side recovere the posted back value and apply it to the control. I.e., read the hidden field value, and set the `Enabled` property of the button accordingly.